# php function not running once user enters data on the form

Tags: php

The function T_CONTINUE does not run and gives the error of Undefined index: city1 on line 82, along with city 2 and city 3. The rest of the if statments do work verifying the input from the user. If the user forgets to enter a part of the form the first individual error messages show and then the genral errMessage should show but does not.

After the user enteres all correct information and continue ==true then it should post back what they selected in the form.

```
 <HTML> 
    <head>
    <h1>Weather Wizards Registration Verification Form</h1>
<hr>
<br>
  <?php //start PHP codeing
    $name=
    $parentName=
    $email=
    $phone=
    $member=
    $city1="";
    $city2="";
    $city3="";
    $nameErr="";
    $parentNameErr="";
    $parentEmailErr="";
    $parentPhoneErr="";
    $memberErr="";
    $errMessage ="";
    $continue=true;

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST"){
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
    $parentName = test_input($_POST["parentName"]);
    $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
    $phone = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
}
function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {  //Name
  if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
    $nameErr = "You forgot to enter your name.";
    $continue==false;
    echo $nameErr;

  } else {
    $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["parentName"])) { //Parent Name
    $parentNameErr = "You forgot to enter your parent or guardian’s name";
    echo $parentNameErr;
    $continue==false;
  }else {
    $parentNameErr = test_input($_POST["parentName"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["email"])) {  //Email
    $parentEmailErr = "You forgot to enter your parent or guardian’s email.";
    echo $parentEmailErr;
    $continue==false;
  }else {
    $parentEmailErr = test_input($_POST["email"]);
  }
  if (empty($_POST["phone"])) { //phone number
    $parentPhoneErr = "You forgot to enter your parent or guardian’s phone";
    echo $parentPhoneErr;
    $continue==false;
  }else {
    $parentNameErr = test_input($_POST["phone"]);
  }
   if (empty($_POST["member"])) { //membership
    $memberErr = "You forgot to enter your membership status.";
    echo $memberErr;
    $continue==false;
  }else {
    $memberErr = test_input($_POST["member"]);
  }
}
T_CONTINUE();
// if ($continue) { T_CONTINUE(); }

    function T_CONTINUE(){
  if($continue = false){
    $errMessage = "We need your name and your parent or guradians name,email,phone and your membership status to send information about our workshop. Hit the back button on the browser to try again";
    echo $errMessage;
  }else if ($continue =true){
if( $_POST["city1"]){
    // if Charleston is selected:
    echo"You are nearest to our Charleston SC location, the Holy City! Go River Dogs!";
}else if( $_POST["city2"]){
    // if per Summerville is selected:
 echo"You are nearest to our Summerville SC location, the Birthplace of Sweet Tea! Refreshing!";
}else if( $_POST["city3"]){
    // if per Mt. Pleasant is selected:
 echo"You are nearest to our Mt. Pleasant, SC location that has a historical and beachy vibe!";
}
}
}

  ?> 
</body>
<style type="text/css">
html{
    background-color: lightgray;
}
</style>
</HTML>
```

Comment: So the function `T_CONTINUE()` is not running, even though it gets called on the last line? Do you have error reporting enabled, and if so, is everything executing without any errors or warnings?

Comment: `T_CONTINUE()` refers to a bunch of variables that are never set: `$email`, `$parentName`, `$name`, etc.

Comment: `$_POST[($name)]` should probably be `$_POST['name']`

Comment: What is `test_input()`?

Comment: You keep undoing the assignment to `$continue`. If name is not set you set `$continue = false`, but then if parent name is set you change it back to `true`. You should initialize it to `true` at the beginning, and then if any input isn't set you should change it to `false`.

Comment: But you never use `$continue` after all the validation checks. It should probably be something like `if ($continue) { T_CONTINUE(); }`

Answer (score 1):

So there are couple of problems with what you have.

1. Inside the `T_CONTINUE` function, you assign `false` to `$continue`. You are doing an assignment instead of a comparison. `=` vs `==`
2. In order to access the global variable `$continue` you need to use the global array like `$GLOBALS['continue']`.
3. During development, turn on error reporting to `ALL`. Makes debugging easier. Would not have helped much in this case since you were doing an assignment in the condition and that is technically not illegal.

Comment: Where would I add the $globals['continue'].

Comment: in place of `$continue`